# Qt SSL server only visible in the local network

Tags: qt, networking, ssl

I have a working SSL server implementation, but the problem is that the server is visible only for devices in my local network, and can't be accessed from outside.

Is this a common problem for servers, or have I done something wrong? Could it be my Linux distribution limiting the visibility?

Best regards,
Rat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are behind a [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) firewall which most modem/router/switch all-in-one boxes use, then you will need to set up port forwarding on the router.

Port forwarding allows an incoming connection on a port on the WAN side of the modem/router to get forwarded to a LAN computer.

See http://portforward.com/ for help setting up port forwarding.